# HTML2Canvas not previewing image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Im sorry for asking this question again i found out what line of code is not working can someone help me fix the problem?

here is the error

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.renderContent ((index):83)
renderContent @ (index):83
```

index 83 is

```
 html2canvas([document.getElementById('myid')], {
```

this is canvas

```
    function renderContent() {
    html2canvas([document.getElementById('myid')], {
        allowTaint: true
    }).then(function (canvas) {
        result.appendChild(canvas);
        download.style.display = "inline";
        download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
    });
}
```

Script src

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

  <script src="https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you loading the required library before your script?

Comment: yes i am i will insert my script src

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark but have you tried `html2canvas(document.getElementById('myid'), {` Also the script for *https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js* returns 404.

Comment: @NewToJS   what script for html2canvas should i use?

Comment: Maybe this will be of some help [**Github Html2Canvas**](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) and this for [**Html2Canvas Documentation**](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#getting-started)

Comment: thank you for all your help all i had to do was host html2canvas

Comment: Happy to help. I wish you luck in your further development, have a great day!